# What is the correct format respond to Apple pass webservice get serial

Tags: c#, wcf

This is the format I am using

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var collection = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var update = new List<LastUpdate>();
update.Add(new LastUpdate
   {
      lastUpdated = DateTime.Now,
      serialNumbers = new List<string> { "12345678907654" }
    });
responseMsg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
responseMsg.Content = new StringContent(jss.Serialize(update), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return responseMsg;
```

I have also try using this format

```
collection.Add("lastUpdated", DateTime.Now);
collection.Add("serialNumbers", new List<string> { "12345678907654" });
responseMsg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
responseMsg.Content = new StringContent(jss.Serialize(collection), 
Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return responseMsg;
```

but the lastUpdated is always null, so could someone help me resolve the issue, and I am also using WCF to create my webservice.

Comment: No idea what your title means

Comment: With the pass webservice there is a get serial which, and once the pass send a get response you need to respond with a json. If you look at the code I tried both of those format and none of them work, so I need help figuring out what is the correct format

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for answering follow up questions for your question, but please [edit] your question to add any relevant information, so people coming here in the future won't have to dig through all the comments